# add Google Fit distance (DataPoint out of range)

Tags: android, kotlin, google-fit

My code

```
val startTime = 1510241100000 // 2017-11-09T15:25:00+00:00
val endTime = 1510241180000   // 2017-11-09T15:26:20+00:00
val distance = 12000.0f

val distanceDataSource = DataSource.Builder()
    .setAppPackageName(packageName)
    .setDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
    .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
    .build()
val distanceDataSet = DataSet.create(distanceDataSource)
val distancePoint = distanceDataSet.createDataPoint()
    .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
distancePoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_DISTANCE).setFloat(distance)
    distanceDataSet.add(distancePoint) // here is the crash
```

crashed with **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataPoint out of range**, if the diff between **startTime** and **endTime** is less then 10 minutes.

Has someone an idea, what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*TL;DR: The code is OK, but you are trying to add a `DataPoint` that is (in the API's eyes) bogus: you can't go over 100 meters/second*

There are some internal validations in the API that check for limits on the input data, and throw an exceptions if the data doesn't comply.

Some decompiled code that shows these limits (in particular, you are interested in `com.google.distance.delta`):

```
private zzbtw() {
    HashMap var1;
    (var1 = new HashMap()).put("latitude", new zzbty(-90.0D, 90.0D, (zzbtx)null));
    var1.put("longitude", new zzbty(-180.0D, 180.0D, (zzbtx)null));
    var1.put("accuracy", new zzbty(0.0D, 10000.0D, (zzbtx)null));
    var1.put("bpm", new zzbty(0.0D, 1000.0D, (zzbtx)null));
    var1.put("altitude", new zzbty(-100000.0D, 100000.0D, (zzbtx)null));
    var1.put("percentage", new zzbty(0.0D, 100.0D, (zzbtx)null));
    var1.put("confidence", new zzbty(0.0D, 100.0D, (zzbtx)null));
    var1.put("duration", new zzbty(0.0D, 9.223372036854776E18D, (zzbtx)null));
    var1.put("height", new zzbty(0.0D, 3.0D, (zzbtx)null));
    var1.put("weight", new zzbty(0.0D, 1000.0D, (zzbtx)null));
    var1.put("speed", new zzbty(0.0D, 11000.0D, (zzbtx)null));
    this.zzhbn = Collections.unmodifiableMap(var1);
    HashMap var2;
    (var2 = new HashMap()).put("com.google.step_count.delta", zzc("steps", new zzbty(0.0D, 1.0E-8D, (zzbtx)null)));
    var2.put("com.google.calories.consumed", zzc("calories", new zzbty(0.0D, 1.0E-6D, (zzbtx)null)));
    var2.put("com.google.calories.expended", zzc("calories", new zzbty(0.0D, 5.555555555555555E-10D, (zzbtx)null)));
    var2.put("com.google.distance.delta", zzc("distance", new zzbty(0.0D, 1.0E-7D, (zzbtx)null)));
    this.zzhbm = Collections.unmodifiableMap(var2);
}
```

As the times are transformed from your time unit into nanoseconds (see `DataPoint.setTimeInterval`), you end up with 1e-7 (as you are coming from milliseconds), and

Your data:

- Time delta: 80s -> 80000000000
- Distance delta: 12000mts
- Speed: 12000mts/80000000000ns -> 0.00000015mts/ns -> 1.5e-7

Long story short: try 8000 and see it working, try 8001 and see it failing

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any documentation about this, and had to debug step by step to get to this.

Comment: Thanks for the long explanation. I also tried to debug it, but was not successful. You saved my day and now I have to find a solution to show the user anything.

Comment: I doubled checked your answer within the Google Fit app -> "Speed is too high - You can change distance or time". This seems to be an acceptable behaviour for such an exception.